# Custom c++ array freaks out when assigning a value to an index

Tags: c++, arrays, codeblocks, ubuntu-18.04

I need help with error in my custom c++ array. I wanted to create a simple array template class, intentionally ignoring the std array. But when I try to assign a value via index operator, for some reason the array size seems to change and the value does not get stored.

This is my array template class.

```
template<typename T>
class Array
{
       friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream& output,const Array& a)
       {
            //output private ptr-based array
            for (size_t i=0; i < a.length; i++)
            {
                output << std::setw(12) << a.ptr[i];
                if ((i+1)%4 == 0)   //four numbers per row of output
                    output << std::endl;
            }
            if (a.length%4 != 0)      //end last line of output
                output << std::endl;
            return output;
        }

    public:
        Array(const int& arraySize = 0);
        Array(const Array&);
        ~Array();
        Int32 size();

        bool operator==(const Array&) const;
        bool operator!=(const Array&) const;

        T &operator[](Int32);
        const T operator[](Int32)const;

    private:
        size_t length;
        T* ptr;
};

template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array(const int& length):length(length > 0 ? length : throw std::invalid_argument("Array size must be greater than 0")), ptr(new T[length])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        ptr[i] = NULL;
    }
}

template<typename T>
Array<T>::Array(const Array<T>& aryToCpy): length(aryToCpy.size()), ptr(new T[length])
{
    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        ptr[i] = aryToCpy[i];
    }
}

template<typename T>
Array<T>::~Array<T>()
{
    delete[] ptr;
    ptr = nullptr;
}

template<typename T>
Int32 Array<T>::size()
{
    return length;
}

template<typename T>
T& Array<T>::operator[](int subscript)
{
        if (subscript < 0 || subscript >=0)
            throw std::out_of_range("Subscript out of range");

        return ptr[subscript];
}

template<typename T>
const T Array<T>::operator[](int subscript) const
{
        if (subscript < 0 || subscript >=0)
            throw std::out_of_range("Subscript out of range");

        return ptr[subscript];
}

template<typename T>
bool Array<T>::operator==(const Array<T>& right) const
{
    if(length != right.length)
        return false;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        if(ptr[i] != right.ptr[i])
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}

template<typename T>
bool Array<T>::operator!=(const Array<T>& right) const
{
    return !(this == right);
}
```

This is my catch2 unit test environment, where i want to test if my array works properly.

```
SCENARIO("Arrays can be created empty.")
{
  GIVEN("An empty Array declaration and a defined length")
  {
    Array<Int16> *testArray;
    Int8 arrayLength = 4;

    WHEN("A new array gets created with empty items...")
    {
        testArray = new Array<Int16>(arrayLength);
        THEN("The size of the array is as defined")
        {
            REQUIRE(testArray->size() == 4);
        }

    }

    testArray = new Array<Int16>(arrayLength);
    WHEN("An empty array with size 4 gets filled up with values")
    {
        std::cout << "Array size start: " << testArray->size() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Array index 0 (before): " << testArray[0] << std::endl;
        testArray[0] = 1;
        std::cout << "Array index 0 (after): " << testArray[0] << std::endl;
        testArray[1] = 2;
        testArray[2] = 3;
        testArray[3] = 4;


        THEN("The array is now filled with values")
        {
            std::cout << "Array size test: " << testArray->size() << std::endl;
            REQUIRE(testArray[0] == 1);
            REQUIRE(testArray[1] == 2);
            REQUIRE(testArray[2] == 3);
            REQUIRE(testArray[3] == 4);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like you forgot the assignment operator `Array& Array<T>::operator=(const Array<T> &);`. See the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: `testArray` is a pointer.  You need `(*testArray)[index]`.  Dupes are so hard to find for this.

Comment: You seem to be leaking all of your arrays. Is your background perhaps in a garbage-collected language? If you `new` an object, you must `delete` it when you're done with it. Though if you must use dynamic allocation, modern code should use smart pointers instead. And in this case, there doesn't seem to be any reason to use dynamic allocation.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux OP is implementing their own vector, how can they avoid dynamic allocation?

Comment: Please include a _complete_, _compilable_ example, _with_ `#include`s. Where is "Int32" coming from? etc.

Comment: @SergeyA I meant in regard to `testArray`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

try change "if (subscript < 0 || subscript >=0)" to "if (subscript < 0 || subscript >= length)"

Comment: It worked in combination with the hint of Nathan Oliver to dereference the  array before using the index-operator. Thank you so much :)

Comment: You allocated memory in heap: 
Array<Int16> *testArray = new Array<Int16>(arrayLength);
And use (*testArray)[index].
But you can use it locally (stack).
Array<Int16> testArray(arrayLength);
And use testArray[index].
When you allocate memory in heap you should free it
delete testArray;